# Aerial firefighting kata python

Tags: python

I have built a code for a codewars problem. I think it is correct but it shows me an error I don't understand.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
import math


def waterbombs(fire, w):
    s=""  
    countx=0
    for i in fire:
        if i=="x":
            countx+=1

        elif i=="Y":
            countx=0
    return sum(math.ceil(countx/w))


waterbombs("xxYxx", 3)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Curso Python Pildorasinformaticas\Ejercicios Codewars\Aerial Firefighting.py", line 16, in <module>
waterbombs("xxYxx", 3)
  File "D:\Curso Python Pildorasinformaticas\Ejercicios Codewars\Aerial Firefighting.py", line 13, in waterbombs
return sum(math.ceil(countx/w))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

[Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: What would the sum of a single value be?

Comment: `math.ceil()` gives you an `int` result. `sum()` works on iterables (that would, e.g., contain `int`s). Contrast `sum(1)` (which will give you the error message you received) and `sum([1])` which will give you `1` as the answer, because this is summing an iterable (in this case, a list) with an `int` in it (so, `sum([1, 2, 3])` would give you `6` etc).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `sum(math.ceil(countx/w))` ?
What is the objective of the `sum` method here, since there is only value returned by math.ceil ?

The sum would throw that error if you pass a single value to it. You're supposed to pass a list of values of the `sum` method.

For eg: `sum(5)` would give you the same error you see above, but `sum([5])` would return you 5.